# Paragraph indent after multicols environment

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, multicol

I'm using the `multicol` package and have found that the paragraph immediately following the `multicols` environment is indented. This happens even when there is no blank line between the end of the environment and the beginning of the next paragraph.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \lipsum[3-5]
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

So how can I avoid the indent? Thanks!

PS. How can I show the PDF of my MWE here?

Comment: reply to `How can I show the PDF of my MWE ?` is [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2137/15717)

Comment: You can just upload the pdf as an image, the site will convert to a low res bitmap, although better is usually to crop it yourself in a bitmap editor and upload that (or use the standalone class which tries to automatically crop the page to the visible area)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the implied question is how to stop the indent. You can use `\noindent` to stop the indent for a single para or `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` to globally 0 the indentation. The following paragraph is just a normal paragraph there is no interaction from the preceding multicols (unlike a section head)

Comment: So, the end of environment creates a new paragraph. Is it right?

Comment: `\end{env}` doesn't necessarily imply a new para but in the case of multicols, it implies several ends of paragraph:-) The paragraph at the end of the multicol text is ended and the text balanced, the balanced two column text is placed onto the page, the _page_ is then ended to invoke the output routine which will then switch back to the single column output routine re-inserting the page-so-far with the two columns as a box at the top of the page, inserting some vertical space and then finally starting a new paragraph for teh following text...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to make the paragraph after a `multicols` environment responsive (with respect to its indentation) to `\par` (or an empty line) before it by appending `\@doendpe` to the definition of `\endmulticols`. (This is the mechanism used by list environments.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto{\endmulticols}{\@doendpe}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \sometext
\end{multicols}
%
\sometext

\bigskip

\sometext

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \sometext
\end{multicols}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose this would be something the `multicol` package author would have to do, right? (Now that you've edited the answer, I can see the answer to my follow-up question.)

Comment: This is a good answer if needed to be done for the whole document.

Comment: @Jeremy it is even a good answer if it is only needed some times in a document, basically it changes the need for saying \noindent to using or not using an empty line. However, it is not something I could add to multicols without breaking a lot of documents and in fact the standard usecase would be that the env ends the paragraph so requiring manual \noindent in the few exceptions is not that bad.